# commons net ftp issue

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am facing an issue where it appears that my FTP connection is correct and no errors are received, but the file is not placed on the ftp server.

I am using commons-net-ftp.

Code:

```
        int retCode = 0;

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));

    InputStream input = null;
    try
    {
        int replyCode;

        client.connect(pHostName);

        replyCode = client.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode))
        {
            client.disconnect();
            logInfo("ftpFile() - FTP Server refused connection");
            retCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(client.login(pUserName, pPassword))
            {
                //default is FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE
                if(this.isBinaryTransfer())
                {
                    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);   
                }

                // Use passive mode as default because most of us are
                // behind firewalls these days.
                client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                input = new FileInputStream(pLocalFileName);

                if(this.isRemoveRemoteFile())
                {
                    client.deleteFile(pRemoteFileName);
                    client.getReply();
                    this.logReplyStringInfo(client.getReplyStrings(), "Removing Remote File");
                }

                if(this.isOverwriteFile())
                {
                    replyCode = client.sendCommand("-O");
                    this.logReplyStringInfo(client.getReplyStrings(), "Overwrite File");
                }

                if(!client.storeFile(pRemoteFileName, input))
                {
                    logError("ftpFile() - Not able to store the file on the server" ); 
                    retCode = 6;
                }

                input.close();
                client.logout();
                client.disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                client.logout();
                client.disconnect();
                retCode = 3;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {
        logError("ftpFile(String, String, String, String, String)", fileNotFoundException); //$NON-NLS-1$

        fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        retCode = 5;
    }
    catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e)
    {
        logError("ftpFile(String, String, String, String, String)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$

        retCode = 4;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logError("ftpFile(String, String, String, String, String)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$

        e.printStackTrace();
        e.printStackTrace();
        retCode = 2;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (client.isConnected())
        {
            try
            {
                if(null != input)
                {
                    input.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException f)
            {
                logWarning("ftpFile(String, String, String, String, String) - exception ignored", f); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
        }
    }
```

Log File Trace:

> 2010-10-12 10:57:53,527 INFO  [STDOUT] 230 Logged in successfully
>   2010-10-12 10:57:53,527 INFO  [STDOUT] PASV
>   2010-10-12 10:57:53,576 INFO  [STDOUT] 227 Entering Passive Mode (216,27,89,17,10,231)
>   2010-10-12 10:57:53,624 INFO  [STDOUT] STOR SharperImageFeed2.txt
>   2010-10-12 10:57:53,681 INFO  [STDOUT] 150 "/SharperImageFeed2.txt" file ready to receive in ASCII mode
>   2010-10-12 10:57:54,337 INFO  [STDOUT] 226 Transfer finished successfully.
>   2010-10-12 10:57:54,337 INFO  [STDOUT] QUIT
>   2010-10-12 10:57:54,384 INFO  [STDOUT] 221 Windows FTP Server (WFTPD, by Texas Imperial Software) says goodbye

Any suggestions as to what the issue is? Any test that can be run?

I can ftp and upload a file using FileZilla.

---

Doing further testing I am able to execute a successful FTP put when I run from my local dev env - which is Windows (Eclipse/JBoss)  But, when the FTP is run from the production servier (Linux/JBoss) The trace indicates that it is successful but nothing is placed on the FTP Server.

Answer (score 4):

A few of the commands with Commons FTP require you to call completePendingCommand:

```
 if(!client.completePendingCommand()) {
     client.logout();
     client.disconnect();
     System.err.println("File transfer failed.");        
     System.exit(1);
 }
```

Try adding the above after storeFile.  More info here:

[http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#completePendingCommand()](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#completePendingCommand%28%29)

Comment: I added the above but it caused the method to hang.

Comment: This works for me with the completePendingCommand uploading to a Linux server.